# Save div = contenteditable to MySQL using PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, post

Is there any possibility to save a DIV, that has contenteditable="true", to a MySQL Table? I need to use PHP for this (and JS as a "helper").

I though of doing something like this:
Putting a button on the site that copies the content of the contentEditableDIV to a formDIV (a DIV that is in a form with method="POST" action="send_to_mysql.php").
The button is supposed to auto-trigger the submit button/function at the same time.

But is there any other, **more convenient way**? I am quite a beginner in MySQL, so I couln't think of any other way yet.

I appreciate any kind of help or response.

With best regards,

Dave

Comment: The answer is fairly complex, and involves JS + AJAX and PHP + (your choice of database handling, I prefer PDO). There is no easy copy/paste answer, but I'm sure there are tutorials out there for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually...

```
//contenteditable element
//read element with JS
//URIencode to PHP via JS/AJAX
//Send to database with PHP/PDO
```

You're in for a real can of worms if you want this to work well. *Especially if you want this to work well AND be able to accept pasted content from MS Word.*

Comment: Thanks for the response! 
That really sounds more complicated than I wanted it to be... I think I should rethink my system.

Comment: @DaveTheAl It really is. You can "simplify" it by using a pre-made editor (such as TinyMCE, CKEditor) but you'll still have to setup the database exchange. If you don't know what you're doing you can have a real mess on your hands (XSS attacks and whatnot). I recommend looking into the open-source software I mentioned and reading up on PDO. Whatever you do, do not use MySQL - it's depreciated, and for good reason.

Comment: Thank you greaty for your response! You're being a greate help. I just started a new thread as I should have been more discrete with my question :)